# Does this prime-gaps pattern occur infinitely often?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th prime.

For each integer $k \ge 0$, do there exist
an infinite number of $k+3$ consecutive primes
$(p_n, p_{n+1}, \ldots, p_{n+2+k})$
so that

- (1) The gap between the 1st and 2nd, and between the
  2nd and last, are equal: $p_{n+1}-p_n = p_{n+2+k}-p_{n+1}$.
- (2) There are $k$ primes between the 2nd and last,
  i.e., between $p_{n+1}$ and $p_{n+2+k}$.

<strike>For $k=0$, the answer is *Yes* by the recent breakthroughs on prime gaps.</strike>
Here are some examples:

      [image: PrimeGapsk]

One could whimsically imagine "skipping" a flat stone on the primes,
where the first bounce covers the gap between
the 1st and 2nd primes, followed by $k+1$ smaller
bounces that
together cover the same gap before sinking on the last prime.

Comment: Likely yes.  No proof yet.  Stay tuned.  Also, this would follow from the k-primes conjecture, which seems more likely to be answered before your question.

Comment: Terry Tao might weigh in on whether one could "Maynardize" (sorry!) his and Ben Green's work on primes in arithmetic progressions to produce a more regular pattern.  That's one chance I see of this being answered positively before k tuples conjecture.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger how *exactly* would you use k-tuples conjecture?

Comment: In fact, you might tweak your write up to say that the case k=0 follows from the work on arithmetic progressions on primes, which is less recent than what many might think.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger as far as I can see it does *not* follow from results on progressions in primes (since nothing guarantees the primes to be *consecutive*, which is also the point of my first comment)

Comment: @quid, its quite possible that I am confusing my idea with what is actually in the literature.  My recall is that if an admissible pattern of prime gaps occur, then that pattern occurs infinitely often WITH no extra primes "inside" the pattern. What might be in the literature instead would have the constellation occur as a proper subconstellation, allowing extra primes.

Comment: I guess I need to review the literature, as I had the impression that the progressions were of consecutive primes.  Perhaps I am confusing Tao and Green's work with work on 3-tuples occurring infinitely often.  If so, I apologize for the chatter.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger the work of Green and Tao is not for consecutive primes; it is not even known if there are 3-AP of *consecutive* primes (wheras 3-AP of primes is "ancient"). For k-tuples conjecture, yes, I think it is also conjetured for consecutive, but I was under the impression it is more common not to insist on this in that conjecture too.

Comment: @quid: I removed the claim that the $k=0$ pattern---three consecutive primes in arithmetic progression---is resolved by recent results. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: In the illustration for $k=1$, 47 should be 43 (I'd fix it myself, but pretty displays are beyond my TeXnical level).

Comment: Sharp eyes, Gerry! Corrected---Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This would follow from the $k$-tuple conjecture in the following way.

Choose an admissible tuple $d_1, \ldots, d_{k+2}$, such that $d_2-d_1=d_{k+2}-d_2$. If $n\in[d_1, d_{k+2}]$ is an integer, such that $\{d_1, \ldots, d_{k+2}\}\cup\{n\}$ is admissible, pick a prime number $p$ such that for all $i$ we have that $n-d_i$ is not divisible by $p$. Pick integers $e_i>d_{k+2}$, such that $\{d_1,\ldots, d_{k+2}, e_1, \ldots, e_\ell\}$ is admissible, and the set $\{d_1,\ldots, d_{k+2}, e_1, \ldots, e_\ell\}$ covers all residue classes modulo $p$ with the exception of $n\pmod{p}$. Repeat until you arrive at an admissible set $D$, such that $D\cap[d_1, \ldots, d_{k+2}]=\{d_1, \ldots, d_{k+2}\}$, and for all $n\in[d_1, d_{k+2}]\setminus\{d_1, \ldots, d_{k+2}\}$ we have that $D\cup\{n\}$ is not admissible. Apply the $k$-tuple conjecture to the set $D$. If $x+d$ is prime for all $d\in D$, and $x$ is sufficiently large, then $x+d_1, \ldots, x+d_{k+2}$ are consecutive prime numbers.

Comment: Wow! That is an impressively nontrivial connection to the $k$-tuple conjecture!